# Tunneling of electrically neutral objects

Tags: atoms, molecules, quantum-tunneling

The question is motivated by a [joke-question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/538588/is-corona-virus-using-quantum-tunneling-to-spread-itself/538592#538592) posted in this forum, but it is serious: *How would we calculate the tunneling probability for a multi-particle/multi-atom object with zero net charge?*

The treatments of tunneling in the QM textbooks usually make the following implicit assumptions:

- The object is a particle or particle-like
- The object is charged (hence we can define the potential)

I suggest to consider the following cases:

- Toy example: How would we calculate the probability of an atom tunneling out of a closed reservoir?
- Realistic example: How would we calculate probability of an organic molecule tunneling through the cellular membrane?
- Example with realistic numbers: a hydrogen atom encolosed by a metallic sphere.

**Clarification**
I am looking for a mathematical formulation for such tunneling.

Comment: I has to be done with the energy levels defined by the band theory of solids. found this by google " band theory of solids and tunneling" https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0003491666902892  and  more recent https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.5133039 with holes etc